# Spring Security. error 401 in browser but not in postman

Tags: javascript, jwt

There are two pages.  The first is login, the second is chat.  If the user enters his login data correctly, the server will send him a jwt token.  Next, clicking on the button, the user must go to the chat page, which requires the user to be authorized.  When sending a request via postman with a token, everything is fine.  The chat page is shown When I do the same in the browser, when I go to the chat page I get a 401 error :( I don’t understand what the error is, really. Here is part of the configuration:

```
auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/login", "/signup", "/index.html", "/signup.html", "/css/signup.css", "/js/signup.js", "/login.html", "/css/login.css", "/js/login.js", "/js/chat.js", "/css/chat.css").permitAll(); //сделано

                    auth.requestMatchers("/chat.html", "/chat").authenticated();
```

login.js

```
document

  .getElementById("usernameForm")

  .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var username = document.getElementById("name").value;

    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/auth/login", true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var data = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });

    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onload = function () {

      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if (response.user == null) {

          displayError();

        } else {

          let jwt = response.jwt;

          localStorage.setItem("token", jwt);

          goToChat(jwt);

        }

      } else {

        console.log("Ошибка");

      }

    };

  });

function goToChat(jwt) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/chat", true);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  xhr.onload = function () {

    if (xhr.status == 200) {

      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/chat";

    } else {

      console.error("Error", xhr.status);

    }

  };

  xhr.send();

}
```

I also tried transmitting through the cache, but it doesn’t accept the cache either.  If you go to the developer tools in the browser, the cache is transferred correctly.  It feels like my program simply doesn’t process the jwt token in the cache or in the header, so it doesn’t allow the user to access the chat page.
Maybe I don't have some processing in the configuration

Comment: Google what CORS is, also enable your spring security debug logs and update your question with the full log

Comment: I think that everything is fine with CORS, because the page (which requires authorization) opens when I allow access to it without authorization (I write permitAll and restart the server, the page opens).  Or could CORS still be configured incorrectly even with this outcome?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to work with Cookie. Tokens are stored in the header for only 1 request. Then they fell. Therefore, they need to be stored somewhere. For example, in Cookies. Of course, I also changed CORS. But the main thing that had to be done was to add a filter to the configuration that would read the token from the cookie and process it